# How use check origin in library socketio (verifyClient)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

How use check origin in library socketio (verifyClient)?

How use check header origin?

In library - 'ws' it do

```
  var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({
  port: 8081, verifyClient: function(info, callback) {
                          if(info.origin != null){
                            if(info.origin == 'http://ws-nodejs') {
                               callback(true);
                              }else{
                               callback(false);
                              }
                          }
      });
```

How use it in socketio ?